# SSIS Check Excel source rows redirect rows to another table on 'x' number of field matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, data-import

I work in a sales based environment and our data consists of 'leads'.

Let's say we record CompanyName, PhoneNumber, Address1 & PostCode(ZIP).  These rows a seeded with a unique ID in the schema.

The leads come in from various sources and are compiled onto a spread sheet and then imported into SQL 2012 using SSIS.

After a validation check to see if a file exists we then use a simple data flow which consists of an Excel source, Derived Column, Data Conversion and finally an OLE DB Destination.

My requirement I'm sure has a relatively simple solution.  I understand what I need to achieve is the first step.  I need to take a sample of data from the last rolling two months, if 2 or more fields in the source excel file match the corresponding field in the destination sql table then I want to redirect to another table.

I am unsure of which combination of components I could use to achieve this.  I believe that Fuzzy lookup may not be what I am looking for as I am looking to find exact field matches, I have looked at the lookup component but I am unsure if this is the way to go.

Could anyone please provide some advice on how I can best achieve this as simply as possible.

Comment: There is one way to do this task. Just to clarify the following questions:  do you know exactly which fields will be in the source, and what does mean "sample of data from the last rolling two months"? Thanks

Comment: Yes, CompanyName, PhoneNumber, Address1 & PostCode(ZIP). Every day we import data, so I get all data in the last two months as criteria to check for duplicates in a dataset.  Suffice it to say this is a business rule.  I need to check to see if CompanyName & Phone or CompanyName & Address1 or CompanyName & PostCode(zip) match the destination cross checking the dataset in the last two months.  These are then scored as similar or duplicate.  I hope this is clear

Comment: I am wondering if this would fit my requirement but I am unsure of how implement... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31030/Performing-Data-Merge-and-Audit-with-SSIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lookup to check for matches in your existing table.   However, it will be fairly complicated to implement the requirement of checking for any two or more fields matching.   Your expression would be long and complex basically consisting of:

(using pseudo code for readability)

> IIF((a=a AND b=b) OR (a=a AND c=c) OR (b=b AND c=c) OR ...and so on
>   for every combination of two columns you want to test

I would do this by importing the entire spreadsheet to a staging table, and doing the existing rows check in a SQL stored proc that moves the data to the desired destination table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The sample is not 'from' my two month data, the sample 'is' the two month data, my problem has somewhat evolved so I am now going to update my question.